# DatePicker me resta 1 dia a la fecha!

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, datepicker

Mi problema esta en que en mi programa yo cargo una fecha para un registro a traves de un datepicker, esa fecha la guardo en la base de datos, todo como tipo Date. Luego cuando yo llamo la lista de los registros guardados en la base de datos y la muestro en un table view la fecha se me ve modificada y me resta exactamente 1 dia de todas las fechas cargadas... La verdad es que no se me ocurre si puede ser un problema de alguna libreria o el driver de mySQL, necesito ayuda.
Mi gestor de base de datos es phpMyAdmin, estoy usando JavaFx en [netbeans-8.2](/questions/tagged/netbeans-8.2).

Aqui pongo mis clases:

Clase Viaje (la cual es del tipo que se guarda en la BD.

```
public class Viaje {

private IntegerProperty idViaje;
private Date fecha;
private StringProperty origen;
private StringProperty destino;
private StringProperty tipoNota;
private StringProperty nota;
private IntegerProperty cantidadKm;
private IntegerProperty dniChofer;
private StringProperty idAuto;
private StringProperty horaSalida;
private StringProperty horaRegreso;
private FloatProperty importe;

public Viaje() {

    this.idViaje = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.origen = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.destino = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.tipoNota = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.nota = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.cantidadKm = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    this.dniChofer = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    this.idAuto = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.horaSalida = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.horaRegreso = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.importe = new SimpleFloatProperty();


}

public Viaje(Integer idViaje,Date fecha,String origen,String destino, String tipoNota,String nota,Integer cantidadKm,Integer dniChofer,String idAuto,String horaSalida,String horaRegreso, Float importe){
    this.idViaje = new SimpleIntegerProperty(idViaje);
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.origen = new SimpleStringProperty(origen);
    this.destino = new SimpleStringProperty(destino);
    this.tipoNota = new SimpleStringProperty(tipoNota);
    this.nota = new SimpleStringProperty(nota);
    this.cantidadKm = new SimpleIntegerProperty(cantidadKm);
    this.dniChofer = new SimpleIntegerProperty(dniChofer);
    this.idAuto = new SimpleStringProperty(idAuto);
    this.horaSalida = new SimpleStringProperty(horaSalida);
    this.horaRegreso = new SimpleStringProperty(horaRegreso);
    this.importe = new SimpleFloatProperty(importe);
}

public int getIdViaje() {
    return idViaje.get();
}

public void setIdViaje(int idViaje) {
    this.idViaje.set(idViaje);
}

public IntegerProperty idViajeProperty() {
    return idViaje;
}

public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getOrigen() {
    return origen.get();
}

public void setOrigen(String origen) {
    this.origen.set(origen);
}

public StringProperty origenProperty() {
    return origen;
}

public String getDestino() {
    return destino.get();
}

public void setDestino(String destino) {
    this.destino.set(destino);
}

public StringProperty destinoProperty() {
    return destino;
}

public String getTipoNota() {
    return tipoNota.get();
}

public void setTipoNota(String tipoNota) {
    this.tipoNota.set(tipoNota);
}

public StringProperty tipoNotaProperty() {
    return tipoNota;
}

public String getNota() {
    return nota.get();
}

public void setNota(String nota) {
    this.nota.set(nota);
}

public StringProperty notaProperty() {
    return nota;
}

public int getCantidadKm() {
    return cantidadKm.get();
}

public void setCantidadKm(int cantidadKm) {
    this.cantidadKm.set(cantidadKm);
}

public IntegerProperty cantidadKmProperty() {
    return cantidadKm;
}

public int getDniChofer() {
    return dniChofer.get();
}

public void setDniChofer(int dniChofer) {
    this.dniChofer.set(dniChofer);
}

public IntegerProperty dniChoferProperty() {
    return dniChofer;
}

public String getIdAuto() {
    return idAuto.get();
}

public void setIdAuto(String idAuto) {
    this.idAuto.set(idAuto);
}

public StringProperty idAutoProperty() {
    return idAuto;
}

public String getHoraSalida() {
    return horaSalida.get();
}

public void setHoraSalida(String horaSalida) {
    this.horaSalida.set(horaSalida);
}

public StringProperty horaSalidaProperty() {
    return horaSalida;
}

public String getHoraRegreso() {
    return horaRegreso.get();
}

public void setHoraRegreso(String HoraRegreso) {
    this.horaRegreso.set(HoraRegreso);
}

public StringProperty HoraRegresoProperty() {
    return horaRegreso;
}

 public float getImporte() {
    return importe.get();
}

public void setImporte(float Importe) {
    this.importe.set(Importe);
}

public FloatProperty ImporteProperty() {
    return importe;
}
```

Controlador de la Pantalla principal donde cargo el registro y lo guardo en la base de datos:

```
public class PrincipalController extends ControladorBaseDatosA {

@FXML
public void apretarRegistrarViaje(ActionEvent event) {

    ControladorViaje controladorV = new ControladorViaje();

    ControladorBaseDatosA id = new ControladorBaseDatosA();

    if (siEsInvalidoPrincipal()) {
        Viaje v1 = new Viaje();

        //Obtengo el metodo de id autoincrementable
        v1.setIdViaje(id.idViajeAutoIncrementable());
        v1.setOrigen(tOrigen.getText());
        v1.setDestino(tDestino.getText());
        v1.setTipoNota(tTipoNota.getText());
        v1.setNota(tNota.getText());
        v1.setCantidadKm(Integer.parseInt(tCantidadKm.getText()));
        v1.setIdAuto(tIdVehiculo.getText());
        v1.setDniChofer(Integer.parseInt(tDniChofer.getText()));
        //Obtengo la fecha del date picker
        v1.setFecha(java.sql.Date.valueOf(tFecha.getValue()));
        //Aca guardo los valores de hora 
        v1.setHoraSalida((sHoraSalida.getText()));
        v1.setHoraRegreso((sHoraRegreso.getText()));
        v1.setImporte(Float.parseFloat(sImporte.getText()));

        clickRegistrarViaje = true;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Viaje registrado con exito");
        controladorV.insertarSQL(v1);
        limpiar();

    } else {
        if (tOrigen.getText().equals("") || tDestino.equals("") || tTipoNota.equals("") || tNota.equals("") || tCantidadKm.equals("") || tIdVehiculo.equals("") || tDniChofer.equals("") || sImporte.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese algun dato");
            System.out.println("Ingresa algo vivo!");
        }
    }
}
```

Metodo utilizado para llegar los campos del tableview:

```
public void llenarViajes(Connection connection, ObservableList<Viaje> listaViaje) {
    try {
      Statement ps = connection.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM viaje");
        while (rs.next()) {
            listaViaje.add(new Viaje(rs.getInt("idViaje"), rs.getDate("fecha"), rs.getString("origen"), 
                rs.getString("destino"),rs.getString("tipoNota"), rs.getString("nota"), rs.getInt("cantidadKM"), 
                rs.getInt("dniChofer"),rs.getString("idAuto"),rs.getString("horaSalida"), rs.getString("horaRegreso"),
                rs.getFloat("importe")));
        }  
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Clase controladora de la ventana donde se encuentra el tableview que se llena con los datos guardados en la base de datos:

```
public class AdminViajesController extends ControladorBaseDatosA implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Button atras;
@FXML
private TableView<Viaje> lista;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Viaje, String> idColumna;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Viaje, Date> fechaColumna;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Viaje, String> origenColumna;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Viaje, String> destinoColumna;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Viaje, String> tipoNotaColumna;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Viaje, String> notaColumna;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Viaje, Integer> kmColumna;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Viaje, Integer> dniChoferColumna;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Viaje, String> idAutoColumna;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Viaje, String> hSalidaColumna;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Viaje, String> hRegresoColumna;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Viaje, Float> importe;

private ObservableList<Viaje> listaViaje;



@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resouces){
    listaViaje = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ControladorBaseDatosA db = new ControladorBaseDatosA();
    db.llenarViajes(db.getConexion(), listaViaje);
    lista.setItems(listaViaje);

    idColumna.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("idViaje"));
    fechaColumna.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fecha"));
    origenColumna.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("origen"));
    destinoColumna.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("destino"));
    tipoNotaColumna.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("tipoNota"));
    notaColumna.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nota"));
    kmColumna.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cantidadKm"));
    dniChoferColumna.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dniChofer"));
    idAutoColumna.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("idAuto"));
    hSalidaColumna.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("horaSalida"));
    hRegresoColumna.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("horaRegreso"));
    importe.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("importe"));

}
```

Me olvide de mencionar que a la hora de cargar los datos, la fecha me la guarda correctamente en la base, es decir si ingreso por ejemplo 20-11-2018 es tal cual la fecha que aparece en la BD, pero que al llenarse el tableview me altera la fecha restandole 1 dia a todas.

Paso a mostrarle un par de fotos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Phpmyadmin no es un gestor de base de datos, es la ide con la que ingresas a la misma. Es imposible saber que pasa, sin ver tu codigo. Tambien, verificaste si los datos se guardan bien? y si vienen bien desde la base de datos?

Comment: Podría ser problemas del time zone. Pon algo de código

Comment: Esto es raro. Podes tracear tu codigo, y verificar que en el metodo llenarViaje, los datos esten bien?

Comment: el servidor de base de datos y donde esta el backend es el mismo?

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó algo parecido hace tiempo, y resultó ser un problema con el TimeZone configurado en PHPMyAdmin.

PHPMyAdmin tiene una configuración de TimeZone para cada usuario, con lo cual, si estas consultando una fecha en un TimeZone diferente al de PHPMyAdmin, le va a aplicar la diferencia de horas a la fecha que muestra.

Para asegurarte de que la fecha que esta grabada en la BD es la fecha que te muestra PHPMyAdmin, debes consultar directamente la BD con un gestor de BD que no sea PHPMyAdmin.

Probablemente lo que esté pasando es que introduces una línea y se grabe bien la fecha en la BD, pero al mostrarlo en PHPMyAdmin te lo modifica a su TimeZone, y en el programa obtienes la fecha real de la BD.

Comment: TimeZone de mysql

Comment: @JackNavaRow a mi me paso con el timezone de phpmyadmin, no de MySQL, y puede que este introduciendo bien las fechas y despues al mostrarlas salgan cambiadas

Comment: entonces es el timezone de php

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con

```
rs.getObject("fecha", LocalDate.class)
```

Revisa [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47934432/7700985) respuesta, tal vez por allí esté la solución.

Comment: y porque no la traduces y la agregas, recuerda que existen usuarios de habla hispana no saben ingles

Answer (score 0):

Esto mismo me ha pasado hace unos días en JavaScript. El problema es que el datepicker te recoge la fecha en formato local, mientras que la base de datos te está guardando las fechas en formato UTC. Lo que debes hacer es leer la fecha de la base de datos y convertirla a tu formato local.

Te dejo el siguiente enlace donde muestra ejemplos para convertirlas en ambos sentidos:

[Convert Date to LocalDate or LocalDateTime and Back](https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-to-localdate-and-localdatetime)

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Yo le sume un día al darle a aceptar (para que el usuario no viese nada) con este código.

```
this.dia =  new Date(this.form.value.fechaNacimiento);
this.dia = new Date( this.dia.setDate(this.dia.getDate() +1));
this.form.patchValue({
  fechaNacimiento: new Date(this.dia)
})
```

Comment: Hola, por favor, añadé más información a tu respuesta, así como mas detalles de porqué sería la solución correcta.